# Laravel: Good Approach

Tags: laravel

I have been into `Laravel` since a month or so. I have almost covered its most of the features. What I want to ask is, "Is it a good approach to put all the code in a single Controller in `Laravel`?"

Comment: Nope! Each controller has its tasks. The MVC approach dictates this: Every Model has its specific tasks and every controller too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totaly a not "good approach" to do that! If you do it, you didn't respect S.O.L.I.D. principles.

You should take a look of ['Real Life' L5/L5.1 app example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/real-life-l5l51-app-example)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful in making me understand laravel even better!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any question feel free to ask they, here or in Laracast.